# Cleaning a Symfony project and installing a new bundle

Tags: php, symfony

Im very new to Symfony, yet Im already familiar to the MCV model, after a while reading the documentation I have now the standard edition of Symfony 2 running on my server.

### Fresh start

As you know Symfony comes with a hello world app and some welcome scripts, how can I clean all of that?, even better, is there a way to install a Symfony project without the examples bundles?

### Data base structure restore

In the past, every time I developed an app with database, I created the structure of the tables using *phpmyadmin* and then an initial php script that restore that database if I need to install my app on other server. Working with Symfony is quite different, I read that it use doctrine and the Symfony core restore the database format using some internal files. I have a bundle that I need to install, I know that this bundle/app use MySQL, I set the config file with all my MySQL information but I dont know how I can run a sript that will restore a clean database needed for that particular app. I know it has something to do with `php app/console schema:update` but not so sure.

Thanks for any orientation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I clean all of that?, even better, is there a way to install a Symfony project without the examples bundles?

There is no way to do that in Symfony2 and it looks like it never become a part of the Symfony2 project:

> *"I think that we need clear instructions on how to remove the Acme demo code by hand. I'm -1 on added a CLI command to do that automatically.
> "*
>   -- [fabpot on github](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/pull/412#issuecomment-10153889)

The things you should do:

1. Remove the `src/Acme` directory
2. Remove `$bundles[] = new Acme\DemoBundle\AcmeDemoBundle();` (line 25) in `app/AppKernel.php`
3. Remove the related routes from `app/config/routing_dev.yml` (`_welcome`, `_demo_secured` and `_demo`)
4. You **can** remove everything in the `security:` key in `app/config/security.yml` and place `enabled: false` in it. However, this isn't needed and it works like a nice boilerplate for your own security

---

Your other question: Symfony2 don't have a 'view' layer. You can choose to use whatever you want. But Symfony2 included 2 ORMs in their framework by default, Doctrine and Propel. You can read more on how to work with these libraries in the documentation: [Doctrine](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html) and [Propel](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/propel.html).

Comment: Thanks, regarding the second answer, im not interested on a view layer, i will like only to install a bundle that use mysql.

Comment: Does it use doctrine? You can run `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force` to create all needed schema's and mapping data.

Comment: Yes it use doctrine, can you please be more specific about the command use, I mean, i have the new bundle (a zip file with the common struture app src web), do i just need to copy that to my www\Symfony\src ?

Comment: Which bundle is it? The best thing you can do is to install it with composer if you use Symfony2.1. If it doesn't have a composer package, you should copy the content of the zip in `vendors/<vendor-name>/`. If you are using Symfony2.0 (you shouldn't) you need to add this to the autoload configuration, read more about that in the installation guide of that bundle

Comment: the problem is that the bundle is not a public one, somebody make a bundle in symfony and after that he copied the dir strutture and compress it...

Comment: Well, copy it in the `vendor/` directory and make sure Composer can autoload the classes

Comment: Sorry for being so ignorant, Ive never worked with frameworks in past (I did all the parts of my php codes), how can I know if composer can load the classes? He will also create the tables?

Comment: I think you are trying to go too fast.  Take a step back, read the introduction parts of the manual, understand how the acme demo bundle works, read through the Doctrine manual, dissect your 3rd party bundle a bit, etc.  There is no majic.  Gonna have to understand the basics.

Comment: If you have a bundle named `MyBundle`, copy that dir to your src/ and add a line in your app/kernel.php
If there is extra config, copy/paste these parts to your corresponding files.
Note: this is not the cleanest way to do that but it might works.

Comment: @martinqt please, do not recommend things that aren't the good way.

Comment: Concerning the fresh start, there's even an official cookbook entry: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/remove.html